# HQL query.list() returns null list of size 1 when no rows are there in table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, list, collections, hql

HQL select statement is returning a null List with size 1, for -

```
Query qry = session.createQuery("SELECT min(date) FROM  Appointment").setCacheable(true);
List list = qry.list();
```

Now, list == null or list.isEmpty() both returns false. Also, list.size() is 1. If I look at list object it shows size 1 and all objects are null.

Hibernate Query translates to select min(appointm0_.APPT_DATE) as col_0_0_ from appointment tnappointm0_;
Running this actual query, returns no rows.

[image]

How to check, whether query returned any results ?

Comment: Looks like this issue is because of min() function. Just doing a select on table with 0 rows, returns a list with size 0 However elementData still has 10 null elements